# Using the Azure Devops pipeline preview API to preview final pipeline yaml

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I am trying to use the [pipeline preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/preview/preview?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) API for Azure DevOps to get the compiled final yaml of my target pipeline, but my query is ending in error.

I am using the below Powershell:

```
$method = "Post"
$pat = "secret"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($pat)"))
$headers = @{ Authorization = "Basic $token" }

$url = "https://dev.azure.com/organisation/project/_apis/pipelines/193/preview?api-version=7.1-preview.1"

$body = @{
   previewRun = $true
   resources = @{              
      repositories = @{
         self = @{
            refName = 'refs/heads/main'
         }
      }
   }
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Method $method -Headers $headers -URI $url -Body $body -ContentType "application/json"
```

And receiving an internal error response:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id:
e266f381-40e9-4a55-afd0-766164d64028.","typeName":"Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException,
Newtonsoft.Json","typeKey":"JsonReaderException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Method $method -Headers $headers -URI $url -Body $ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

I have double checked with other APIs that the auth headers are working. I suspect there is the body may be problematic.

I was referencing [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66013587/23215931) when crafting this query.

Comment: In my experience you should convert the body to JSON with `ConvertTo-Json -Compress` before passing it to `Invoke-RestMethod`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix the request body:

1. convert to json for your body.
2. In PowerShell, $true is a reserved keyword representing a boolean value. You can use $previewRun instead if you would like to dynamically set the value.

I edited your powershell and it works for me as below:

```
$method = "Post"
$pat = "secret"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($pat)"))
$headers = @{ Authorization = "Basic $token" }

#parameters
$organization = "orgname"
$project = "Projectname"
$pipelineid = "pipelineid"
$previewRun = "true"



$url = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/pipelines/$pipelineid/preview?api-version=7.1-preview.1"

$body = @{
   previewRun = $previewRun
   resources = @{              
      repositories = @{
         self = @{
            refName = 'refs/heads/main'
         }
      }
   }
} | ConvertTo-Json


$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method $method -Headers $headers -URI $url -Body $body -ContentType "application/json"
$response | ConvertTo-Json
```

[image]